# How Can I Use More Than One Index-Pattern In A Visualization In Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have three index pattern that contain metrics for my application.  I'd like to be able to correlate the time series data of this index-patterns at the same time on the SAME visualization.  Is that possible?  I've done this in Grafana before and I'm trying to do the same in Kibana but I'm not sure how.

I'm doing this so I can super-impose on set of metric data over another and have the user be able to see what the app is doing and what the host is doing.  For instance, showing the API call latencies in a bar chart an then "super-imposing" metrics from another index-pattern (such a memory etc) seamlessly in the same visualization.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: You can use the Lens visualization tool, which allows you to select different index patterns in the same chart.
[image]

Option 2: You can use the TSVB visualization tool, which allows you to set different index patterns for different metrics. To do so, you need to go to the "Options" tab of a metric, select "Yes" below "Override Index Pattern?" and set the desired index pattern in the text field besides.
[image]

Option 3: You can create a new index pattern that matches all the indices matched by the three original index patterns. Then, you can use the more inclusive index pattern to create visualizations.

Comment: I read about that and it looks cool.  Unfortunately, we're a bit behind in our ES versioning and we are hosting in-house.  It looks like lens is a SaaS offering?

Comment: Kibana Lens is available from version 7.10 both on the Elastic Cloud and Self-Hosted with the Elastic License. Another solution would be to use [Timelion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-tutorial-from-zero-to-hero) to plot data from differents index.

Comment: I see let me update the answer by adding TSVB

Comment: Was your question answered, @KSS?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!  I'm going to look into update our ES self-hosted stacks so we can take advantage of these new features.